# digital clock in screenlock mode on Android

Tags: lockscreen

I am thinking i would be more productive if i would have a digital clock which displays the seconds too (so that i am constantly reminded that time passes quickly)

But i just not finding any on Google Play.

Isn't there any?

I can only find screensavers, but not clock displays while the phone has locked screen.